# Windows phone application bluetooth connect

Tags: c#, windows-phone

How can I connect my windows phone device with the other devices by bluetooth using my app in c#? So I can send message to each others using my app too or I can create multiplayer game to play through this bluetooth connection.

Answer (score 2):

The following example shows how to create a Bluetooth RFCOMM socket connection to connect your app to a device:

[Windows Phone 8 Networking Samples](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/3-047)

Basically, you have to create a socket connection with a paired Bluetooth device:

```
PeerFinder.AlternateIdentities["Bluetooth:PAIRED"] = ""; 
var available_devices = await PeerFinder.FindAllPeersAsync(); 
if (available_devices.Count > 0) 
{            
   PeerInformation pi= // Select the device  
}
StreamSocket socket = new StreamSocket(); 
await socket.ConnectAsync(pi.HostName, "1");
```

This example was shown in Build 2012 conference. You will find the video of the presentation here:

Windows Phone 8: Networking, Bluetooth, and NFC Proximity for Developers (Build 2012)

[http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Windows-Phone-8-Networking-835239c1](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/3-047)